# Python: How to take values from a list of lists and insert them into list of tuples

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

I would like to know how to take the string values from a list of lists, and insert those values into the corresponding lists of tuples.

Where I can take the values from:

```
[[0, 92, 8, 'GREEN'], [0, 82, 18, 'RED']]
```

I want to insert the string values into the respect list of tuples below:

```
[[(0, 92, 8), (0, 93, 7), (0, 91, 9), (1, 92, 7), (1, 91, 8)],
 [(0, 82, 18), (0, 83, 17), (0, 81, 19), (1, 82, 17), (1, 81, 18)]
```

So the output should look like this:

```
[[(0, 92, 8, 'GREEN'), (0, 93, 7, 'GREEN'), (0, 91, 9, 'GREEN'), (1, 92, 7, 'GREEN'), (1, 91, 8, 'GREEN')],
 [(0, 82, 18, 'RED'), (0, 83, 17, 'RED'), (0, 81, 19, 'RED'), (1, 82, 17, 'RED'), (1, 81, 18, 'RED')]
```

The pattern would be to take the string value from the first code snippet, and insert that into the end of each tuple within the corresponding list[].

```
# to try and clear it up 
[[0, 92, 8, 'GREEN'] # lets call this list 1
 [0, 82, 18, 'RED']] # and this list 2

# list 1 corresponds with this list of lists of tuples 
[[(0, 92, 8), (0, 93, 7), (0, 91, 9), (1, 92, 7), (1, 91, 8)] 

# list 2 corresponds with this list of lists of tuples
[(0, 82, 18), (0, 83, 17), (0, 81, 19), (1, 82, 17), (1, 81, 18)]
```

Any ideas? If this question isn't clear, please comment so I can fix it :)

EDIT:

I just realised I can't insert values into a tuple because they are immutable. How could I convert the list of lists of tuples, into what I can work with?

FURTHER EDIT:
To include more information and clarify further, I would like to be able to select each tuple within its own list and get a copy that contains the correct colour. An example:

```
#code1                #code2               #code3
[[0, 92, 8, 'GREEN'], [0, 82, 18, 'RED'], [0, 73, 27, 'GREEN']]

# shortened example; each open and close of [] should correspond
# to the above colour codes

# 1st set of []  = #code1 ('GREEN') to be inserted for each tuple
[[(0, 92, 8), (0, 93, 7)], 

# 2nd set of [] = #code2 ('RED') to be inserted for each tuple
 [(0, 91, 9), (1, 92, 7)], 

# 3rd set of [] = #code3 ('GREEN') to be inserted for each tuple
  [(1, 91, 8),[(0, 82, 18)]]
```

It's the tuples inside the list brackets that I want to insert the colour into, hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so you can't insert anything into them. You can use a list comprehension to build up a new list of tuples. Seems like a homework problem. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @JohnColeman List comprehension is new to me and I am not sure how to approach the problem from the syntax side of things. Should I update my question with the code that lead me from having a list of lists, but returned a list of lists of tuples? I had to change it to a tuple to be able to make it hashable

Comment: The best approach would be to convert `[[0, 92, 8, 'GREEN'], [0, 82, 18, 'RED']]` into a dictionary `d = {(0, 92, 8): 'GREEN', (0, 82, 18): 'RED'}` (this can be done manually or with a dictionary comprehension) and then use that, with the key to use seemingly drawn from the first elements of the other lists.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. So the number values would be checked against the start of the tuples inside the list of lists of tuples? This could give me incorrect string values from the overall data set, and I would have to make a copy but as lists not tuples? 
Do you know a way to convert the list of lists of tuples, into a list of lists of lists?

Comment: Your clarification makes it even more confusing. What is the *point* of the numbers in "#code 2" if all that you care about is `'RED'`? What is the relationship between the codes and the lists? Do you just have a list of "codes"  (which contain 3 irrelevant (for this purpose) numbers followed by a string) and an equal length list of lists?

Comment: The list of sublists of tuples contain those values directly related within the `[ ]`. The list of sublists of tuples contain the information of each of the 'codes' with +- values. @flaberenne answer worked for this use case if you want to check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, it corresponds to what you need but  here is an idea:

```
# res to store the results
# a is the first list 
# b the 2nd
res=[0 for x in range(len(a))]
for i in range(len(a)):
    res[i]=[]
    for z in b[i]:
        # from tuple to list
        y=list(z)
        # add the string (4th elt from the 1st array)
        y.append(a[i][3])
        # from list to tuple
        zz=tuple(y)
        # append to result
        res[i].append(zz)
# print result
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to use it but I am getting the error `for z in no_dups[i]: 
IndexError: list index out of range` where `no_dups` is my second list, the one without the strtings. `no_dups` is a list of lists of tuples

Comment: Wasn't able to edit my comment because of the time limit.  Changing the code into the equivalent of `for z in b` and not `for z in b[i]`, I can see the output is now a list of a single list containing tuples. Maybe this could be causing problems?

Comment: You're welcome.

I make the assumption that the two lists have the same size (size(a)==size(b))
Maybe this is not the case then i could be higher thant no_dups size ?

Comment: Your code is correct, you made me delve deeper into my own code and I saw the problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

This should give you some ideas:

```
colors = [[0, 92, 8, 'GREEN'], [0, 82, 18, 'RED']]

d = {tuple(x[:3]):(x[3],) for x in colors}

lists = [[(0, 92, 8), (0, 93, 7), (0, 91, 9), (1, 92, 7), (1, 91, 8)],
 [(0, 82, 18), (0, 83, 17), (0, 81, 19), (1, 82, 17), (1, 81, 18)]]

new_lists = [[t+d[sublist[0]] for t in sublist] for sublist in lists]

print(new_lists)

#prints [[(0, 92, 8, 'GREEN'), (0, 93, 7, 'GREEN'), (0, 91, 9, 'GREEN'), (1, 92, 7, 'GREEN'), (1, 91, 8, 'GREEN')], [(0, 82, 18, 'RED'), (0, 83, 17, 'RED'), (0, 81, 19, 'RED'), (1, 82, 17, 'RED'), (1, 81, 18, 'RED')]]
```

When I created the dictionary, I made the values tuples of length 1 since I wanted to be able to concatenate them onto the tuples in the sublists. Note that `tuple('GREEN')` would be `('G','R','E','E','N')` (a tuple of length 5), rather than `('GREEN',)` (a tuple of length 1), which hopefully explains why I used the syntax that I used.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, massively appreciated it. Trying to unpack the information. Your code works exactly as it should, however, I am working through the code for my data and it is only returning 'GREEN'. Must be something wrong with my code further up!

Comment: Maybe it is to do with for x in colors? Because I have more 'lists' than I do have 'colors'. The '' is to signify the variable names you used

Comment: @helloworldnoob In your example, the color that you use to tag a list seemed to be a function of the first tuple in that list. The only way that you will see nothing but green is if each of your lists begins with the tuple `(0,92,8)`. By the way -- you can use backticks as [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for code on Stack Overflow. Replace the single quotes in 'colors' by backticks and it will display as `colors`.

Comment: In that example it did that is true. In the output it is based on the the inside list containing tuples, that would correspond to the dictionary. How could I identify the inside lists `[]` and insert the colour to the corresponding list position from the dictionary?

Comment: @helloworldnoob You really should pick examples which are sufficiently representative of your problem. You haven't provided enough information to answer your question. If you aren't using the first tuple to decide which color to use, how are you deciding? You have provided no answer to that question.